# Don't really want a Web Dev version of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I got this version of Ubuntu v12.10 desktop (AMD64) online, burned it to disc back on 2013-01-30, and finally got around to installing it alongside Windows 7 Pro x64 on this box.  I haven't even checked to see if it dueal boots as expected...  Here's the problem and it may or may not actually be a problem.  This installation booted up as "Ubuntu Studio" and at first glance seems tailored for Web developers or other types far more artistically inclined than I am.

If "Ubuntu Studio" is meant to be similar to "Visual Studio" in connotation, a programmer's environment, I can deal with it.. If it is a Web developer's platform it will mean a lot of work deleting crap I don't want or need and installing a version of 12.10 that actually is loaded with programmer's tools.

What I'd really like to do is completely uninstall this thing and make sure Windows7 Pro still boots and performs as it did yesterday, then install a cleaner, more useful-to-me version of Ubuntu.

So far, I'm liking the look of the UI of this version of Ubuntu...the last one I used much was v10.4, I think.

Anyway, is there a way to, and should I bother to, install a more software development oriented edition of Ubuntu on this machine without hosing it in the process?  In my experience, uninstall routines are often disastrously buggy.  I do have the option to just wipe the 256GB SSD and restore it from the RAID1 virtual drive I use for backup and long-term storage.  I'm hoping someone has a better solution to what may be a non-problem.

[Added a few minutes later...]  I'm gonna figure out how to keep this desktop's appearance...too much orange gets on my nerves, but light grays and blues are easy on tired eyes.

Comment: Why not just install normal "Ubuntu" and install additional software you need as you need it?

Comment: `"Ubuntu Studio" is meant to be similar to "Visual Studio"` nope.... Ubuntu Studio: Designed for multimedia editing and creation. Has nothing to do with web development.

Comment: Can I do that and completely overwrite this variation in the process?  If so, you've answered my question.

Comment: @fractalzone format the partition and install Ubuntu: yes.

Comment: OK, I think we can call this question answered.  I did create the Ubuntu partiion manually using a partitioning utility under Win7, so wiping it and recreating it is no big deal...as long as the boot process defaults back to Win7 at least temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Studio is just tuned more for multimedia editing and stuff, if you need a development platform for web dev or similar, you're better off starting from scratch.

Format your Ubuntu partitions, and then install normal Ubuntu, and install web development software, or whatever software you need, as you need it.

(answer shamelessly stolen from @Rinzwind's comments on the question :P)

Comment: Nice, Lord of Time.  Guess I have to wait another 2.5 minutes to accept your and one other's replies as useful answers. :)